# OSX: Avoid userprompt when opening embedded binary

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, mac-app-store

I have a sandboxed app that uses an embedded binary to show it's status item.
On first launch of the main app (where it launches the embedded binary like this:

```
 NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchApplication(statusItemPath)
```

) OSX displays a user prompt, if the user really wants to start the embedded app:
[image]

I find this really confusing for the user - I understand that it is for security reasons but I want to distribute via MAS and so both binaries needs to pass review.

Is there a way to avoid this user prompt (maybe a singing option or entitlement key?)

Answer (score 2):

When an application is downloaded from the internet, or run via another program for the first time, OS X is protecting the user with a mechanism known as ['quarantine'](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201940).

Once the user accepts running the application, the quarantine extended attribute on the app is removed.

Removing the quarantine attribute can be done with the following command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /PATH/TO/APPLICATION
```

So you could call out to the system to run this from your initial application on the embedded binary. However I'm not sure this would be acceptable to Apple for the App Store.

The preferred method would be to use XPC and create a helper app which is launched automatically by launchd. You can read about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html).